# std::is_same for void function(...) and void type?

Tags: c++, type-traits, std-function

I got this piece of code:

```
template <class FunctionType> class Entry {
    std::function<FunctionType> internalFunction;

    template<class... Arguments>
    auto operator()(Arguments... arguments) -> decltype(internalFunction(arguments...)){

        if (std::is_same<decltype(internalFunction(arguments...)), void>::value) {
            internalFunction(arguments...);
        } else {
            auto result = internalFunction(arguments...);

            return result;      
        }
    }
};
```

Entry class is meant to be wrapper for `std::function`. It works for all return types with one exception - `void`. I can't get it to work. I have also tried `std::is_void`, it doesn't return true for function of type `void(...)`. The same for `std::is_same`.

How to get around this problem?

Comment: `internalFunction` returns `std::function`. I can't figure out what you are trying to check. `internalFunction` will never return `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows another solution, that one based on *sfinae* instead of *partial specialization*.
I tried to provide a minimal, complete example.
I'd also have introduced the *perfect forwarding* in the example, but it would have been pretty different from the one in the question, so I decided to leave it more similar to that one.

```
#include<functional>
#include<type_traits>


template <class FunctionType> class Entry {
    std::function<FunctionType> internalFunction;

    template<typename R, typename... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_void<R>::value>::type
    invoke(Args... args) {
        internalFunction(args...);
    }

    template<typename R, typename... Args>
    typename std::enable_if<not std::is_void<R>::value, R>::type
    invoke(Args... args) {
        return internalFunction(args...);
    }

public:
    Entry(std::function<FunctionType> f)
        : internalFunction{f} { }

    template<class... Arguments>
    auto operator()(Arguments... arguments) -> decltype(internalFunction(arguments...)){
        return invoke<typename std::function<FunctionType>::result_type>(arguments...);
    }
};


int f() { return 42; }
void g() { }


int main() {
    Entry<int()> e1(&f);
    e1();
    Entry<void()> e2(&g);
    e2();
}
```

For further details about *sfinae* see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

Comment: This is what I needed. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

```
return internalFunction(arguments...);
```

That works even if `internalFunction` returns `void`

Trying to store the result in an intermediate object doesn't work, because you can't create an object of type `void`, because it's not an object type.

Your `if` doesn't work, because `if` is a run time condition, the compiler still needs to compile both branches of the condition and so they must both be valid C++.

If you need to create a variable of the intermediate result type then you cannot use that code for the `void` case. You can write a partial specialization for functions returning `void`:

```
template <class FunctionType> class Entry {
    std::function<FunctionType> internalFunction;

    template<class... Arguments>
    auto operator()(Arguments... arguments) -> decltype(internalFunction(arguments...))
    {

        auto result = internalFunction(arguments...);

        return result;      
    }
};

template <class... ArgTypes> class Entry<void(ArgTypes...)> {
    std::function<void(ArgTypes...)> internalFunction;

    template<class... Arguments>
    void operator()(Arguments... arguments) {
        internalFunction(arguments...);
    }
};
```

That would not work for functions returning `void` but not for functors that return `void`, doing that is a bit harder.

Comment: I have to store the result, it's not the whole code.

Comment: Then you need to specialize the template and have two definitions, one for `void` returns and another for everything else.

Comment: @Nuurek That will make things very ugly - distinguish functions returning void and non void

Comment: I tried it too. Compiler said that function call was ambiguous.